# Can we say anything about $\vert f'(x) \vert$ versus $\vert f''(x) \vert$ if $f$ is concave and goes through the origin?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ that is concave, upward sloping, and goes through the origin.

Are we able to say anything about how $\vert f'(x)\vert$ compares to $\vert f''(x)\vert$, such as whether one is greater than/less than another?

Comment: That seems like quite a broad question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For any $a > 0$, $f(x) = 1-e^{-ax}$ satisfies those conditions, and $|f''(x)/f'(x)| = a$.

More general, let $h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous, positive function. Then
$$
 f(x) = \int_0^x e^{-\int_0^t h(s) ds} dt
$$
satisfies
$$
 f'(x) = e^{-\int_0^x h(s) ds} > 0 \\
 f''(x) = -h(x) e^{-\int_0^x h(s) ds} < 0
$$
so that $f$ is increasing and concave, with $f''(x)/f'(x) = -h(x)$, i.e. that ratio can be equal to an arbitrary prescribed negative continuous function.

Comment: Clever. Thanks this is a nice answer.

Comment: But in this example, for any given $a\ , |f''(x)/f'(x)|$ is constant, which is quite interesting. So I think this is a poor example. However, I agree with the result, that for any upward sloping concave function, the only meaningful connection between $f''(x) $ and $ f'(x)$ is that one is the derivative of the other and integral vice versa.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

Depending on your definition of *concave*, "Concave, upward sloping" is contradictory.  This answer assumes that you intend that $f(x)$ is convex everywhere.

Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx \implies f$ passes through the origin.

$|f'(x)| = |2ax + b|~$ and $~|f''(x)| = |2a|.$

Convex merely implies 2nd derivative positive which implies that $a > 0$.

Consider the following three functions:

$f_1(x) = 1000x^2 + x~ \implies ~|f'_1(x)| = |2000x + 1|,~$
and $~|f''_1(x)| = 2000.$

For $~-(1/2) < x < (1/2), ~~|f'_1(x)| < |f''_1(x)|.$

For $~1 < x, ~~|f'_1(x)| > |f''_1(x)|.$

---

$f_2(x) = x^2 - x~ \implies ~|f'_2(x)| = |2x - 1|,~$
and $~|f''_2(x)| = 2.$

For $~0 < x < 1, ~~|f'_2(x)| < |f''_2(x)|.$

For $~3 < x, ~~|f'_2(x)| > |f''_2(x)|.$

---

$f_3(x) = x^2 + 1000x~ \implies ~|f'_3(x)| = |2x + 1000|,~$
and $~|f''_3(x)| = 2.$

For $~-(501) < x < -(500), ~~|f'_3(x)| < |f''_3(x)|.$

For $~0 < x, ~~|f'_3(x)| > |f''_3(x)|.$